# Error message getting printed twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<div class="alert-message notice fade in">
<strong>Product was successfully updated.</strong>
</div>

<p id="notice">Product was successfully updated.</p>
```

Why is this getting printed out twice?

[image]

applicaiton.html.erb

```
<%= render 'layouts/errors'%>
```

layouts/errors

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
   <div class="alert-message <%= key %> fade in">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times</a>
    <center><strong><%= value %></strong></center>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perhaps the alert notices are being shown twice. Once in the view and once in the layout. Without seeing your view and layout source files it is impossible to know for sure.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you are seeing, what you are expecting to see, and what your layout looks like?

Comment: Editted, i just don't want the second one to show up i dont know where it is coming from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. It looks like it is correct to me, you have a `<div>` with a `<strong>` in it, and a `<p>` with the same message in it.

If you want the second one to not be printed, remove it.

Comment: ? I can't i dont know where it's getting generated from, I know the first one is coming from my flash.each

Comment: Have you checked the partial that is called by the render 'layouts/errors' statement? The additional notice display is probably in there.

Comment: It isnt i've included the partial in my original question it should only be getting printed once.

Comment: I think if you used rails g scaffold, it actually puts a <%= notice %> in the show.html.erb. Do you see it there?

Comment: If not, go to the views/products/ or wherever your views are, and try "grep notice *.html.erb"

Comment: My mistake, you *did* include the layouts/errors in your post. I second @andrewpthorp's comment. Look in the default show.html.erb template produced by scaffold.